# download url in <img> tag on mobile (using cordova )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I want to download the src='url' in `<img>` tag.
I am using download attr but it works fine on chrome browser, but won't work on  mobile. I am using cordova for development.
Following code won't work on my mobile.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click on the w3schools logo to download the image:<p>
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  <img border="0" src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>
<p><b>Note:</b> The download attribute is not supported in Edge version 12, IE, Safari or Opera version 12 (and earlier).</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `download` attribute in not fully supported by all browsers (take a look of browser compatibilities http://caniuse.com/#search=download)

I recommend you to use `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` which allows you to download and upload files, here is the [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/).